# Challenge/response authentication for garage door opener

Tags: challenge-response

I'm building an Arduino based radio garage door opener, and in order to protect it from replay attacks I've came up with this algorithm:

1. sender initiates communication
2. receiver sends a random 32 bit number XORed with a secret key
3. sender reverses the XOR operation using the same secret key, resolves the challenge (ex: challenge ^ 2 - 5), XORes and sends the result to the receiver together with the command (gate up or gate down)
4. receiver compares the response with it's own calculation of the challenge and executes the command if they match.

I'm curious, do the steps described above ensure that the response is impossible to guess for an attacker?

Comment: Is there any reason public key crypto would be unsuitable in your case? It seems well suited to your problem, and is generally considered secure.

Comment: What about the delayed response attack? User presses door button, attacker intercepts challenge and response and prevents the receiver from receiving the response. User presses it again, attacker re-sends the response (so the door opens) and intercepts the new challenge and response. Now the attacker can re-send the *second* response three hours later when you're asleep.

Comment: I would like to remind everyone that an arduino only has 32kb of ram, and thus may have trouble implementing some forms of full blown complex encryption.

Comment: I've came up with the above "algorithm" because 8 bit microcontrollers that I intend to use have very limited memory (only 2kb in my case).

Comment: @MarchHo He doesn't need public key cryptography... he is able to pre-share a secret key, so he can just use symmetric encryption.  The question is: why isn't he using cryptography at all, which would solve his problem, and instead uses his own weak method...

Comment: @DenisDenisovici I believe that's still plently to implement some form of proper encryption.  AES doesn't really require so much memory, only a few hundreds bytes to store one or two fixed matrices.

Comment: **its** own calculation. please?

Comment: I'd like to point out that a would-be thief is probably getting in through an unlocked door or window, rather than hacking your garage door open. Or they might just lift the door manually. I'm not saying this encryption is a bad idea, just that it's only a small part of being secure.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: On the contrary there are many thieves who cycle garage door keys until they find a working one.

Comment: @Joshua I'm not saying it never happens; in saying that it's only one way of many, and it's important to keep everything in mind to really be secure.

Comment: Speck is a flexible block cipher designed by the NSA for extremely resource-limited embedded devices. It is not nearly as bloated as AES. Perhaps you could use that as well, in addition to very light asymmetric crypto.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

No.

Let's write it up:

- *C* is the challenge message
- *R* is the response message
- *K* is the secret key
- *C = q ⊕ K* where *q* is a random number.
- *R = ((C ⊕ K)<sup>2</sup> - 5) ⊕ K*, or if we skip the decryption step: *R = (q<sup>2</sup> - 5) ⊕ K*.

The attacker can see both *C* and *R*. If the attacker then xors the two values:

*C ⊕ R = (q<sup>2</sup> - 5) ⊕ K ⊕ q ⊕ K*

Since we're xoring with *K* twice, we can just drop those operations out. This gives the attacker the following:

*C ⊕ R = (q<sup>2</sup> - 5) ⊕ q*

There are only a few values for *q* for any given value of *C ⊕ R* in the 32-bit space. In fact, it's an easy enough operation to just brute force: just try all *q* values until you find all the values that match.

This gives you some possible value of *q*, the random number. Since *C = q ⊕ K*, just compute *C ⊕ q* for each candidate *q* to get a small number of possible *K* values. Repeat this process for a second time and see which candidate *K* value came up in both runs: this gives you *K*.

I even wrote a PoC!

```
// our key!
int k = 0xBAD1DEA;

void Main()
{
    // output the key just so we can see it in the output
    Console.WriteLine("Key is: 0x{0:X8}", k);

    int challenge = GenerateChallenge();
    int response = GenerateResponse(challenge);

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Cracking the challenge and response...");

    // this is the attacker: they know only the challenge and respoonse!
    Crack(challenge, response);
}

int GenerateChallenge()
{
    Random rng = new Random();

    // I'm keeping the random number small-ish to avoid the c^2 operation from overflowing
    // this is just a limitation of the fact that .NET has sane integer types that don't wrap on multiplication overflows
    int q = rng.Next(0, 10000000);
    Console.WriteLine("I picked q={0}", q);

    int challenge = k ^ q;
    return challenge;
}

int GenerateResponse(int c)
{
    c ^= k;
    return ((c * c) - 5) ^ k;
}

void Crack(int c, int r)
{
    int c_r = c ^ r;

    // try all possible 'q' values.
    for (int q = 1; q < int.MaxValue; q++)
    {
        if ((((q * q) - 5) ^ q) == c_r)
        {
            // got a match, output it
            Console.WriteLine("q candidate: {0}", q);
            Console.WriteLine("k candidate: 0x{0:X8}", q ^ c);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Key is: 0x0BAD1DEA
I picked q=2847555

Cracking the challenge and response...
q candidate: 2847555
k candidate: 0x0BAD1DEA
```

The "cracking" process took less than a second on my system.

---

**EDIT:** Since this apparently wasn't clear: you're not bruteforcing anything against the real system. This approach doesn't involve you sending any data to the receiver at all. You simply sit there with a software defined radio (SDR) and capture the signals produced when the owner opens their garage door. You then extract the challenge and response values from those signals - these are *C* and *R*. Given *C* and *R* you can use the above process to compute a few possible *q* values for that particular challenge/response pair. In some cases you'll get only one, in some cases you might get 2 or 3. Compute *q ⊕ C* for each candidate *q* to get a list of candidate *K* values. If you get more than one, wait for them to open their garage again and capture another *C* and *R* pair, re-run the process, and see which candidate *K* values match the first time around - this will give you the real *K* value. Once you've got that, you've got everything you need to impersonate the real opener device. You can reply correctly every time since you know the value of *K*.

Comment: Could the server just invalidate the connection after the first invalid response, and thereby issue a new challenge with a different response requirement?  Wouldn't that effectively make brute forcing monumentally harder because you would only get one guess per session?

Comment: Thanks! Since this will be a one off device, the attacker wouldn't know that C ⊕ R = (q2 - 5) ⊕ q. Still, better use some real encryption algorithm.
@JeffMeden yes, I intended to use a 5 min delay in case of a wrong answer, so it would take 38 thousand years under worst case scenario.

Comment: I suppose what he really wants to do is send `q` plaintext and have the receiver reply with `hash(K+q)` (replace hash with your favorite hash function).

Comment: @iAdjunct yes, I think hashing is the universally accepted way to securely respond to a challenge when you just want to prove the client has the key. Since the hash is one-way I believe this protects the client from mistakenly giving up the key to a malicious server, too.

Comment: @DenisDenisovici unless you are really really confident that the wireless stream won't glitch resulting in a wrong answer from the right client, I would suggest a slightly more graduated tarpit like doubling the timeout for each consecutive failure.  If it were me, hitting the remote and having a 5 minute delay because there was a microwave on or something, would cause me to just ram my car through the thing in frustration.

Comment: @JeffMeden You'd never send an invalid response. You brute-force the value of *q* locally until you find one which matches a captured *C* and *R* pair, and repeat until you have a candidate *q* value that appears in the results of multiple captured challenge/response pairs. At that point you know *K* and can produce correct responses just like the real device. The bruteforce approach is just a naive method to get the possible values of *q* - you're not actually sending any challenges.

Comment: @DenisDenisovici The delay won't help secure the mechanism at all, and you're in violation of [Kerckhoffs' principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle). Assume the attacker knows the formula, design your system around that fact. Rate limiting won't help because, as my edit notes, you're passively capturing challenge/response values until you find the value of *K* (usually the first captured unlock, otherwise certainly the second) at which point you can always impersonate the unlocker perfectly.

Comment: @Polynomial ah I see, the issue is with the attacker seeing a successful challenge/response, which lets them reverse it on their own because the formula is sent in the clear. So, would the right approach be to xor the challenge against the secret and then hash it with something suitably hard to reverse?

Comment: @JeffMeden: Why not properly encrypt it then?

Comment: @JeffMeden Or just use a rolling code approach with a hash. *H(k||c)* where k is a shared key and c is an incrementing counter kept track of by both sides. Have the receiver accept any c within a range of 10 of the counter and update when a successful request comes in - this allows the system to continue working even if you press the button a few times out of range of the receiver.

Comment: @MatthieuM. if the only possible piece of data you want to communicate is "the button was just pressed" (like a normal garage door opener) a hash communicates this with minimal CPU and bandwidth overhead

Comment: `PoC == Piece of Code`?

Comment: @cat Proof of Concept.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need a cryptographic function whose relationship between input and output is not readily discernible.  XOR just won't cut it.  A slow but effective way to encrypt the data would be to split the 32 bit value into two halves, H and L, and iterate the following a few times:

- Pad H with enough bytes to make a cryptographic block for DES, AES, or some other decent scheme (and a secret key) and encrypt it.
- Set H to the old value of L, and set L to the old value of H xor'ed with 16 bits from the encrypted block.

If one uses the above approach with a decent encryption method at its core, the result will be a secure 32-bit-to-32-bit mapping.  The inverse mapping can be obtained by swapping H and L, doing the above procedure, and swapping them back.

A 32-bit payload is somewhat small, but could provide a reasonable level of security if challenges are never repeated.  That could be accomplished by having the sender keep a lifetime count of how many challenges have been sent, and using that as the challenge data to be encrypted and validated.

Answer (score 0):

Your step 4 says it all, "receiver compares the response with it's own calculation"

You don't need reversible encryption if the receiver is just comparing the response to a single expected value (it's own calculation)

What you want is to HASH, not encrypt.

Not only does reversible encryption require more hardware, but that reversibility does establish a relationship between the plain text and the cipher text that an attacker can use to determine the secret key.  As mentioned by polynomial in other comments, xor is very weak.

What you want, is to force an attacker to brute force a very large key space.  A one-way hashing function does exactly that.

This is how most challenge response authentication works. The nonce is randomly generated and sent in the clear, then it is hashed with a secret key kind of like a salt. That's the response that gets sent back.  Mutual authentication challenge and response does this twice.

For added security yes, you can iterate the hashing function multiple times.  It makes it more computationally difficult to brute Force.  The receiver need only wait a short time before it forgets it's nonce, eliminating the possibility of replay attack.

Polynomial did mention using a hash table, which is interesting, precisely because that's how most modern garage door openers work today.  Problem with that is, they are subject to rolljam attacks.  An attacker merely forces an out of sync condition which can be exploited.  Challenge and response eliminates that vulnerability because the random challenge is never repeated.